# Dapper.Net and the DataReader

Tags: sql, .net, exception, dapper

I have a very strange error with dapper:

> there is already an open DataReader associated with this Command
>   which must be closed first

But I don't use DataReader! I just call select query on my server application and take first result:

```
    //How I run query:
    public static T SelectVersion(IDbTransaction transaction = null)
    {
        return DbHelper.DataBase.Connection.Query<T>("SELECT * FROM [VersionLog] WHERE [Version] = (SELECT MAX([Version]) FROM [VersionLog])", null, transaction, commandTimeout: DbHelper.CommandTimeout).FirstOrDefault(); 
    }

    //And how I call this method:
    public Response Upload(CommitRequest message) //It is calling on server from client
    {
            //Prepearing data from CommitRequest

            using (var tr = DbHelper.DataBase.Connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable))
            {
                int v = SelectQueries<VersionLog>.SelectVersion(tr) != null ? SelectQueries<VersionLog>.SelectVersion(tr).Version : 0; //Call my query here
                int newVersion = v + 1; //update version

                //Saving changes from CommitRequest to db
                //Updated version saving to base too, maybe it is problem?

                return new Response
                {
                    Message = String.Empty,
                    ServerBaseVersion = versionLog.Version, 
                };
            }
        }
    }
```

And most sadly that this exception appearing in random time, I think what problem in concurrent access to server from two clients.

Please help.

Comment: Do you have another DB query around that code piece ? maybe this piece in a loop that runs another query ?

Comment: Can you please post the whole code ??

Comment: No, I have not another query, I just take version, update it and write to base. I upated my first message and wrote more code. Code is too big and I cut it marginally (commented it)

Answer (score 0):

This some times happens if the model and database schema are not matching and an exception is being raised inside Dapper.

If you really want to get into this, best way is to include dapper source in your project and debug.